# Change the date selection color for specific day in react-calender

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I have used react-calender for creating my calender component.
In this , I want to change the color of date selection for specific days.
I have used `tileClassName`.But it doesn't give me the require output that i want.

[image]

In above,where the date color is red  for that dates i want red selection circle instead of green.Thanks in advance.